# Angular 2+ testing a component

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular6

I have the following service which make a call to an API :

```
export class MoviesService {

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    // Return an obsevable with all the movies from the API
    getAllMovies(): Observable<Movie[]> {
        return this.httpClient.get<EmbeddedTitle>("http://localhost:8080/api/movies", { params: params })
        .pipe(
            map(response => {
                return response;
            }
            ));
}
```

And here's the component that inject that service and call the **getAllMovies** method:

```
export class MoviesListingComponent implements OnInit {

    public movies: Movie[];

    constructor(private moviesService: MoviesService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getAllMovies();
    }

    // Subscribe to method service (getAllMovies) and assign the results to a class object (movies)
    getAllMovies(): void {
        this.moviesService.getAllMovies()
            .subscribe(movies => {
                this.movies = movies;
            });
    }

}
```

I want to know how to unit testing the component's method **getAllMovies** with Jasmine.

Answer (score 0):

the method getAllMovies() changes the value of your "movies" variable and you component has a dependency to the service that hold the data, your job is mock the service and create a getAllMovies that return dummy data and make sure that your movie field hold the data that you mock